# Where I can learn SharePoint 2013 effectively and free of cost?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-2013

My name is Siva. I am working as a sharepoint developer. I don't have any knowledge about the sharepoint 2013. I want to make my self more strong in SharePoint. So kindly someone help me to learn sharepoint 2013 in online free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for free learning use Microsoft's SharePoint development
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SharePoint. For basic training, I would suggest you to go to [rackspace tutorial link](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/resource-center). Go down to video section and start with getting started video. Once you complete all that you can check step by step guide section and then top article.

I assume you have a 2013 environment. Whatever video you see, please perform that on the environment you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could get start to learn SharePoint admin and development from the reference below:

[SharePoint Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sharepoint/)

[SharePoint Learning](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-developer-tutorials-and-samples/)